# reevaluate option has no effect in validation rule

Tags: javascript, validation, devextreme

I have a model, the name field of which is remotely validated for unique values. It works as expected. Now, if I want to update some other properties and don't change the name field, I get the validation error on the name field in this case too. According the devextreme documentation, the `reevaluate` option should set to false in order to not validate the fields, where the value hasn't changed. I configured the validator accordingly, but this has no effect.

Below is the view with the validator configuring script (the other fields are configured via ASP.net validation attributes):

```html
@model Sender

<form asp-action=@(ViewBag.Mode == "new" ? "AddSender" : "UpdateSender") asp-controller="Sender" method="post">
    @using (Html.DevExtreme().ValidationGroup())
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id)
        @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<Sender>()
            .ID("form")
            .FormData(Model)
            .ColCount(1)
            .Items(items => {
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Name).Label(l => l.Text("Név")).Editor(e => e.TextBox().ID("sendername")).IsRequired(true);//.Editor(e => e.Autocomplete()
                //.DataSource(d => d.StaticJson().Url(Url.Action("GetNames", "Sender")))
                //.SearchMode(DropDownSearchMode.StartsWith)
                //.ValueExpr("Name"));
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.Address);
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.ContactPerson);
            items.AddSimpleFor(m => Model.ContactEmail);
            items.AddGroup().Items(groupItem => groupItem.AddSimple().Template(
                @<text>
                    <div style="text-align: right">
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button().ID("save").Text("Mentés").Width(100).Type(ButtonType.Success).UseSubmitBehavior(true))
                        @(Html.DevExtreme().Button().ID("cancel").Text("Mégsem").Width(100).Type(ButtonType.Normal).OnClick("close_onClick"))
                    </div>

                </text>));
            })
            .LabelLocation(FormLabelLocation.Top)
        )
    }
</form>
<script>
    $("#sendername").dxTextBox().dxValidator({
        validationRules: [{
            type: "async",
            message: "Partner with this name already exists",
            reevaluate: false,
            validationCallback: function (params) {
                return DevExpress.aspnet.sendValidationRequest("Name", params.value, "/MasterData/Sender/ValidateSenderName", "POST");
            }
        }, {
                type: "required",
                message: "Field value cannot be null"
           }
        ]
    });     
    
</script>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest will add the `Remote` attribute for 'Name' field of the Model and not create a validator. And I found mistake in your code, you create the dxTextBox for the 'sendername' but it's created afore
in the Razor. This [blog post](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/javascript/archive/2019/12/20/devextreme-asynchronous-validation-v19-2.aspx) describes using the asynchronous validation in the ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC.